# Accessing elements in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable in php, `print_r`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [sum(`Lgsl`.`players`)] => 7769 
        ) 
    )
)
```

And I have a few such arrays with similiar structure. What is the easiest way to get `7769` number from it without referencing to string-key in latest array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list ($number) = array_values($arr[0][0]);
```

The function [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) returns a list of all values with a numeric index, so that you can access the first and only element via index `0`. The `list` keyword can extract array elements into separate variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `array_search()`...

For example you have array `$a`, which is one of yours. Then you can access somehow like this:

```
 $var = $a[0][0][array_search(7769, $a[0][0])]; // to do it perfect, you can add isset() check.
```

Hope, that's is exactly what you need.

**UPDATE:**

Tested by:

```
$a = array(0 => array(0 => array('some' => 7769)));

$var = $a[0][0][array_search(7769, $a[0][0])];

echo $var;
```

Got `7769`.

Comment: I don't know the exact number stored in array. That's just an example (the result of mysql query running).

Comment: If you do not know exact value, and don't know exact key... how you want to be sure you got what you need? That's seems strange to me...

Comment: but he know structure of array :p

Comment: Don't understand... if he know structure... and know that in the first element is exactly what he need, then to grab it, he can use `array_shift()`... Kind of strange logic there...